# Grape Swagger Rails with Markdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger

I am using grape and grap-swagger-rails gems in a rails 5.2 project.  In the past, markdown was supported for individual API `detail` strings. It seems to have been removed.  The stated reason in the commit that removed it is because OAPI accepts [GFM], but as far as I can tell, that is only supported in the overall description of the set of APIs, but not on a per-API basis.

How do I get markdown or other pretty formatting on a per API basis using grape/grape-swagger or some other combination of gems for Rails?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I missed an important detail.  The `detail` strings for individual APIs are already using the GFM markdown!  Using `heredoc` to supply the string allows for very nice looking details.

Here's a contrived example of what a nicely formatted API might look like:

```
 resource :planets do
   desc "Get a list of the planets" do
     detail <<-END
 This is some nicely formatted information with a **bolded** word
 - and
 - some 
 - bullets
 END
   end
   get :planets do
      # ... code to get the planets here
   end
 end
```